# Voice recording from background Blackberry

Tags: blackberry

I am new in Blackberry and I want to record voice automatically from background, Please suggest me how to move further for this. And if possible please give some code.

Comment: actually i don't know whether voice will be recorded from background or not and if yes thn how ? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Record audio on a BlackBerry smartphone](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Record-Audio-on-a-BlackBerry-smartphone/ta-p/445153)

Comment: but i need to record voice notes in background, Any help pls. Thnks

Comment: Recording in a backbround process is possable. You simply use the technique provided above, implemented in a background application. How to write a background application is covered in the BlackBerry Application Programming guide which you should have read from the BlackBerry developer support site where you download the SDK.